# Tag synonym request: [.blend-files]->[blend-files]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[.blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.blend-files) should be synonymized into [blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-files) as they are fundamentally the same and non-aplhanumerics-or-hyphens should be avoided  in tag names whenever possible.

Comment: [feature-request] tags are for adding new functionality to the site.

Comment: @iKlsR It depends on the site; on AU tag synonym requests were often tagged as feature requests and left as such.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ, lets not do that here.

Answer (score 5):

Don't think it should be synonymized. The correct form should be agreed on and left to rule. Not any typing error/off standard is reason for a synonym. They are basically the same thing minus a period (.), we should focus on keeping tags clean and maintainable.

Comment: @iKIsR, Thank you, but perhaps a comment would be more appropriate than an edit in such a case

Comment: I had initially planned to answer, merely added my two cents.

Answer (score 5):

I think they **should** be synonymized. Otherwise, you'd have two tags that mean the same thing instead of one tag that the other points at, which is messier. Personally, I'd prefer to see [.blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.blend-files) synonymized into [blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-files); it looks nicer.

Comment: I think the alternative to synonymizing them is to somehow delete or blacklist the one we want to discourage.

Comment: @Gwenn: The advantage to synonymizing is that if someone starts typing ".blend", then they will see the "blend-files" tag in the choices.