# Tags in need of synonymization

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are some tags that are very much in need of synonymizing, but there isn't anybody on the site with enough rep to request tag synonyms yet. Until then, can we make an informal list of suggestions for tag synonyms here? That way, hopefully the mods will see and make the edits as necessary.

Comment or answer this post with potential synonyms.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some suggestions. Feel free to edit this list.

[.blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.blend-files)  →   [blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blend-files) ([discussion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/tag-synonym-request-blend-files-blend-files))

[.stl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.stl)      →   [stl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stl)

[user-preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-preferences)  →   [preferences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preferences)

[modelling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modelling)     →   [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling)

[node-editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node-editor)   →   [nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes)

[keystroke](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keystroke)     →   [shortcut](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut)

Comment: Some of these spelling variations don't usually constitute adding a tag synonym. Text completion when entering tags are best for that. Synonyms are for different words that essentially refer to the same tag context.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**This is just a comment that got too long to fit neatly in the comments section but still applies to the scope of this question.*</sup>

*IMO* we don't want to be using too many extensions as tags regardless of the fact that they will popup in a search ignoring the prefixed period. Also, some of these are conjugated and make no sense as extensions making it even worse, like [.blend-files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.blend-files) for example.

Regardless, as there are multiple terms or similar words for most of the topics that can be discussed here, it makes sense to set the appropriate ones from now. I agree with Robert Cartaino on his comment that *some of these spelling variations don't usually constitute adding a tag synonym* for several reasons, one being that sometimes a tag should correlate with the tense or manner the accompanying question is phrased.

For one [light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) could refer to lamps and their settings, while [lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting) could refer to best lighting techniques for product renders etc.